# how to have a dropdown of quantities in angular material 2?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

how to have a dropdown of quantities in angular material 2?

the following doesn't seem to work:

```
 <md-list-item>
        <img md-list-avatar src="/images/shirt.jpg" alt="shirt">
        <h2 md-line> Shirt </h2>
        <p md-line> $1.80 </p>
        <md-select placeholder="Quantity">
            <md-option *ngFor="let q of quantities" [value]="q"> {{q}} </md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-list-item>
```

and in my ts file

```
export class BuyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy
{
    quantities: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it's not working, is that you are wrongly trying to assign values to your array `quantities`. You need to assign values with `=`. So instead of

```
quantities: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

it needs to be:

```
quantities = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

This seems to work fine.

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/kJWUdgFS7DugHYstHRSe?p=preview)**